# `schema` keyword usage in GraphQL SDL

Tags: syntax, graphql

I'm trying to understand the meaning and usage of the `schema` keyword on a GraphQL schema definition (SDL).

Let's take the following schema definition, for example:

```
# Enumeration type for a level of priority
enum Priority {
  LOW
  MEDIUM
  HIGH
}

# Our main todo type
type Todo {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
  priority: Priority!
}

type Query {
  # Get one todo item
  todo(id: ID!): Todo
  # Get all todo items
  allTodos: [Todo!]!
}

type Mutation {
  addTodo(name: String!, priority: Priority = LOW): Todo!
  removeTodo(id: ID!): Todo!
}

schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
}
```

Can someone please explain to me the meaning of the `schema` keyword/block in the definition above, why do we anyway need it?

```
schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three types of [operations](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Language.Operations) in GraphQL:

> - query – a read‐only fetch.
> - mutation – a write followed by a fetch.
> - subscription – a long‐lived request that fetches data in response to source events.

In order for your schema to support a particular operation, it must associate a particular object type with it. Each type serves as the *root* or *entry point* to the rest of your schema. This is what this SDL does -- it shows the *root operation type* associated with each operation in the schema. Only the query type is required -- the other two are optional and can be omitted from the definition. Each root operation type must be an object type -- it cannot be a scalar, enum, etc.

Note that by convention the three types are named `Query`, `Mutation` and `Subscription` -- but they could be named just about anything. For example, you could have a schema like this:

```
schema {
  query: Dog
}

type Dog {
  breeds: [Breed!]!
}
```

The name of the type is, for the most part, inconsequential. However, if you follow the standard convention (`Query`, `Mutation` and `Subscription`), the schema definition can be omitted altogether. GraphQL will just assume that the `Query` type is the query root type and so on.

Comment: what do you mean by "Only the query type is required"?

Comment: A schema doesn't have to support all three operations. It might, for example, only support queries and mutations. But it must always support at least queries, so a query operation type is always required -- the other two operation types are optional. http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Root-Operation-Types